# how to use icon fonts with bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icon-fonts

i generated some font-based icons with the online tool icomoon, and am trying to use it with a bootstrap template i have.

**the problem** is that bootstrap's css uses the "icon-" prefix,  and my icon-font uses the same, such as "icon-puzzle" for the css class name.

here's a pic of what's happening (both my custom font (blue puzzle) is being rendered along with a section of the bootstrap icon spritesheet)
[image]

so,  I certainly could change my icon font to use a different css class prefix, such as "font-icon-puzzle",  **but I'd like to properly integrate with bootstrap instead of creating a one-off exception for my font icons.**

Could someone please recommend an alternative that better integrates with bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome is what I use with Bootstrap and it works great:

http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/

In order to get your custom fonts working with Bootstrap make sure you're loading your css after the Boostrap css and make sure your css states "background-image:none" in it.

Comment: Reason for downvoting: typo in the URL and also don't send me to another page... if you're writing an answer then explain in it the steps that must be followed.